# Finding a tree of highest average weight in a directed-weighted graph

Tags: graph

I am searching an algorithm for the following problem: given a directed-weighted graph `G`, find a tree `T` in `G` such that average weight of `T` is maximal.

Comment: Interesting question. Can you give more information about the assumptions on the graphs and constraints on the tree? Is there anything preventing us from taking a tree with only the edge of maximum weight and the two corresponding nodes?

Comment: What do you mean by the _average_ weight of `T`? since If you say that the average is (sum of edge's weight in `T`/number of edges in `T`) then it can be said immediately that pick the edge with highest weight. So cal you please make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

1. Given a graph G
2. Sort Edges in an ascending order (minimum weight first)
3. Cut Top edge (one with smallest weight)
4. Cut orphan vertices
5. Is it a tree now ?

   - Yes: go to step 6
   - No: go to step 3
6. Return G